# AWS - How to add custom userUUD when logging aws Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a few Lambda functions that run using nodejs. In the function code I have a few logs eg consoleLog('email provided') etc

I can also see the logs in cloud watch.

My question: I it possible to set a userUUID on the function so that I can filter cloud watch logs by uuid or tag or something like that?

The app sends a request to AWS gateway, which calls the lambda. In the request, is the UUID. So wondering if I can use that as some type of filter

Thanks

Comment: Does it have to be a custom UUID, or are you happy with one provided by AWS? and if so, how would you generate it?

Comment: Its a custom ID. The app sends a request to AWS gateway, which calls the lamba. In the request, is the UUID. So wondering if I can use that as some type of filter

Comment: If it's in the request, then just get it from there and log it to cloudwatch?